# django queryset annotate and order_by. order_by('quantity') splits results

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm making this queryset in Django. My goal is to list the Top 10 best selling products.
The query works and Sum the two products with the same name.

```
top_10_ordered_products = OrderedProduct.objects.filter(order__in=current_month_orders, vendor=vendor).values('product__product_name').annotate(qty=Sum('quantity')).order_by()
```

Result:

```
<QuerySet [{'product__product_name': 'Café Expresso', 'qty': 10}, {'product__product_name': 'Pão de nozes', 'qty': 15}]>
```

But when adding the order_by('quantity') it separates the summed items in two. One with 10 units and the other with 5.

```
top_10_ordered_products = OrderedProduct.objects.filter(order__in=current_month_orders, vendor=vendor).values('product__product_name').annotate(qty=Sum('quantity')).order_by('-quantity')
```

Result:

```
<QuerySet [{'product__product_name': 'Café Expresso', 'qty': 10}, {'product__product_name': 'Pão de nozes', 'qty': 10}, {'product__product_name': 'Pão de nozes', 'qty': 5}]>
```

Does anyone know how if it is possible to use the order_by without dismembering the same product_name in the query in these case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order by your annotated field `qty`:

```
top_10_ordered_products = (
    OrderedProduct.objects.filter(order__in=current_month_orders, vendor=vendor)
    .values("product__product_name")
    .annotate(qty=Sum("quantity"))
    .order_by("-qty")[:10]
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I feel like a fool. I was more than 12 hours stuck on this... To give you an idea, what I found most convenient as an output was to use the datatables and sort by the column corresponding to the quantity.
But it's so much better and comforting to be able to do it right! I didn't give useful as an answer because I don't have the rating for that yet.
But once again even if for you it's something trivial I am very happy with your help!!!